# cout not outputting after object instantiation

Tags: c++, cout

I have been searching for a while now, but haven't found a useful hint why this is happening, however, it seems to happen to quite alot of people.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

class test{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        test(){x=1;y=1;}
        ~test(){}
};

using namespace std;


int main(void){
    cout<<"hi"<<endl;
    test hiho;
    //cout<<"hi"<<endl;
}
```

This piece of code works fine. However, after uncommenting the last line in the main function, no output is given.

What is happening? (changing the namespace definition doesn't seem to help).

1. Flushing: As has been suggested in previous questions: I am flushing my code.
2. I don't think I have any pointer issues or anything else. I have other code samples that work fine, when objects are instantiated on the global level.

I believe the difference to be that the g++ optimizer removes the object instantiation entirely in the first example since the program ends after that step. That might

Kind Regards

Comment: Working good http://rextester.com/KVI67314

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: No problems here.

Comment: If you do not get any output with the above code after uncommenting the last line, then your system is NOT working properly.

Comment: Yeah it's working fine for me. Try reinstalling your IDE maybe?

Comment: Works for me too

Comment: Unclear: When the program  fails, do you get the first "hi" but not the second or absolutely nothing? What state is `cout` in after the failed call?

Comment: It's possible that in your version you're doing something in the constructor that causes a crash. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Kevin: Please bear in mind, that this actually is a minimal, complete and verifiable example on my machine. Thank you guys! I will reinstall mingw on windows again. I was deeply confused by this behaviour, too.

Answer (score 0):

System was foobar. Reinstall solved the issue.